# I ran regression test in spss and F value appeared to be very high

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, spss

I ran the regression analysis test on spss.The value of F seems to be very large ,it is 137.What is the max accepetable value of F and how can i reduce this value?

Comment: There is no "maximum acceptable value", no good reason to try to reduce the value and no particular reason to think that 137 of itself is "very large" if the null happens to be false.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with your data or with the SPSS output for
your regression. If there is a strong linear relationship between
the predictor variable(s) and the predicted variable, then you may
have a huge F-value and a P-value very near 0. In such a case, nothing
is wrong and nothing needs to be fixed.

Here is a simple linear regression with data simulated in R, along
with output from R for the regression.

```
set.seed(2020)  # include this line for same data in R
x = 1:20
y = rnorm(20, 2*X + 3, 2)
reg.out = lm(y ~ x)
summary(reg.out)
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9308 -1.7354  0.0379  2.2841  3.9649 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.67217    1.18876   2.248   0.0374 *  
x            1.99698    0.09924  20.124 8.66e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.559 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9574,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9551 
F-statistic:   405 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 8.66e-14
```

Notice that the F-statistic here is 405, which is even larger than the
F-statistic mentioned in your question. By looking at a scatterplot of
the data and the regression line $Y = 2.672 + 1.997x,$ you can see that
the data points lie very close to the regression line.

```
plot(x, y, pch=20)
  abline(reg.out, col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum acceptable value, but there are results that are suspicious. The values that are suspicious depend on the field.

In some areas of e.g. physics, you have strong reason to suspect a strong linear relationship and you have good measurements with minimal error.  Then very high F values (even higher than you got) are perfectly reasonable.

On the other hand, in e.g. psychology we have strong reason to *doubt* a strong linear relationship and know that our measurements have considerable error. Then a very high F value (maybe even lower than what you got) would be a cause of suspicion. Not that it's necessarily wrong (you might have gotten lucky) but it might be some sort of data entry problem.

But, to get a feel for what values are surprising, you have to have experience in the substantive area you are in.